# Portfolio Management in R

Tags: r, finance, portfolio, quants

I’ve been looking around for a R-package that will allow me to track my stock portfolio - basically I would like to enter stocks that I own, track the trades I make, calculate my open position & average cost, unrealized & realized P/L, etc… but I have not seen a package that does this.  Has anyone read about/use one with these sorts of functions?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Finance CRAN Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Finance.html)?

Comment: To give you an idea: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/index.html

Comment: The package you are looking for is `PortfolioAnalytics`, which will give you  all relevant measures most reasonable people would imagine for their portfolios (PL, SR, drawdown etc etc etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the [blotter](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/blotter) package. We use it to reconcile our trades.

It's only available on R-Forge, so see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11105131/271616) for how to install it. Run the "amzn_test" demo for an example of how to use it:

```
library(blotter)
demo(amzn_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`PMwR`](http://enricoschumann.net/PMwR/) package, which I maintain, provides such computations. The package is on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=PMwR) and [GitHub](https://github.com/enricoschumann/PMwR)/[GitLab](https://gitlab.com/enricoschumann/PMwR).

Some example code:

```
library("PMwR")

trades <- read.table(text="
 timestamp , instrument , amount , price
2019-06-25 ,     Amazon ,     20 ,  1878
2019-06-26 ,     Amazon ,    -10 ,  1902
2019-07-01 ,     Amazon ,    -10 ,  1921
2019-04-15 ,    Netflix ,     20 ,   362",
header = TRUE, sep = ",",
strip.white = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

trades$timestamp <- as.Date(trades$timestamp)
trades <- as.journal(trades)
trades
##    instrument   timestamp  amount  price
## 1      Amazon  2019-06-25      20   1878
## 2      Amazon  2019-06-26     -10   1902
## 3      Amazon  2019-07-01     -10   1921
## 4     Netflix  2019-04-15      20    362
## 
## 4 transactions
```

`trades` is a `journal`, a list of your trades.

```
summary(trades)
## journal: 4 transactions in 2 instruments
## 
##   instrument  n  avg buy  avg sell       first        last
##      Amazon   3     1878    1911.5  2019-06-25  2019-07-01
##      Netflix  1      362        NA  2019-04-15  2019-04-15
```

From this `journal`, you can now compute positions.

```
position(trades)
##         2019-07-01
## Amazon           0
## Netflix         20

position(trades, drop.zero = TRUE)
##         2019-07-01
## Netflix         20

position(trades, when = as.Date("2019-06-27"))
##         2019-06-27
## Amazon          10
## Netflix         20
```

And you can compute profit/loss.

```
pl(trades)
## Amazon 
##   P/L total        670
##   average buy     1878
##   average sell  1911.5
##   cum. volume       40
## 
## Netflix 
##   P/L total      NA
##   average buy   362
##   average sell   NA
##   cum. volume    20
## 
## ‘P/L total’ is in units of instrument;
## ‘volume’ is sum of /absolute/ amounts.
## ‘sum(amount)’ is not zero for Netflix: specify ‘vprice’ to compute p/l.
```

Since there is an open position in Netflix, we need to provide a price that is used for valuation (`vprice`).

```
pl(trades, vprice = c(Netflix = 380))
## Amazon 
##   P/L total        670
##   average buy     1878
##   average sell  1911.5
##   cum. volume       40
## 
## Netflix 
##   P/L total     360
##   average buy   362
##   average sell  380
##   cum. volume    20
## 
## ‘P/L total’ is in units of instrument;
## ‘volume’ is sum of /absolute/ amounts.
```

The function `pl` can also compute profit/loss over time.

```
pl(trades["Amazon"], along.timestamp = TRUE)
## Amazon 
##   timestamp     2019-06-25 2019-06-26 2019-07-01
##   P/L total              0        480        670
##   __ realised            0        240        670
##   __ unrealised          0        240          0
##   average buy         1878
##   average sell      1911.5
##   cum. volume           20         30         40
## 
## ‘P/L total’ is in units of instrument;
## ‘volume’ is sum of /absolute/ amounts.
```